# Contar quantidade de checkbox selecionados

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tenho um grid com repeater:

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="rtInlineBlock" runat="server">
                        <ItemTemplate>

                            <div class="block">
                                <asp:HiddenField ID="idDirectorio" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("guid") %>' />
                                <asp:HiddenField ID="isFolder" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("isFolder") %>' />

                                <asp:ImageButton ID="btSend" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("imgPath") %>' OnClick="btSend_Click" />

                                <div class="bottom">
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="check" runat="server"  OnCheckedChanged="check_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblNome" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("xInfo") %>'  />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
```

E meu evento de seleção:

```
protected void check_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var cbSend = sender as CheckBox;
        var rtItem = cbSend.Parent as RepeaterItem;

        int cont = 0;
        foreach (var item in rtInlineBlock.Items)
        {

            if (cbSend.Checked)
            {
                cont = cont + 1;
            }
        }
```

}

Tentei dessa forma, mas sempre pega todos os checkbox, quero apenas os selecionados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@WarLock, realmente não entendi por que você precisa contar os CheckBoxes a cada CallBack.

Se você precisar fazer alguma ação que leve em conta os CheckBoxes selecionados, o mais logico seria que o evento fosse disparado por um Button externo ao Repeater.

Mas voltando a pergunta, você pode adaptar o meu método para contar os CheckBoxes selecionados da seguinte fomra:

```
protected void check_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var cont = 0;
    foreach (var rbItem in rtInlineBlock.Items)
    {
        var cbSend = rbItem.FindControl("check") as CheckBox;
        if (cbSend.Checked)
        {
            cont++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: eu ja fiz dessa forma, mas assim ele mostra todos. eu quero justamente pra um botao externo (deletar no caso) deletar mais de um.Entao estava apenas preparando antes. armazenar esses valores, mas ai nao funcionou.

Comment: Não precisa armazenar de forma Prévia, o Button externo pode percorrer os Itens do Repeater e ler os dados do mesmo

Comment: Então como ficaria em outro evento? o evento deletar chama um metodo DeletarDiretorio(),dentro desse método ele pega o cb selecionado, mas so pega apenas 1 o atual que vem no ViewState, então como ficaria, pois se eu chamar o RtItem em outro metodo, da null

Answer (score -1):

Você tem um erro de lógica aí, cbSend é sempre o mesmo objeto dentro do laço, você está fazendo isso:

```
 int cont = 0;
 if (cbSend.Checked)
 {
       cont = rtInlineBlock.Count;
 }
```

A diferença é que eu fiz sem loop.

Se você quer recontar os checkboxes sempre que alguém marcar / desmarcar você precisa pegar `item` e achar o checkbox dentro dele e verificar esse checkbox.

Eu não acho que essa seja uma boa solução, você poderia trabalhar com uma variável que mantenha estado e a cada click somar ou subtrair baseado no valor do checked.

É uma troca, memória por processamento, e nesse caso o custo de memória é muito pequeno para justificar esse processamento repetido, que só piora quanto mais itens entram no repeater.

Vou colocar um exemplo (não sei se vai rodar, se não rodar posta o erro que eu arrumo):

```
protected void check_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        var cbSend = sender as CheckBox;

        // Acho que faltava um convert aqui... null é zero.
        int cont = Convert.ToInt32(Session["cont"]);

        Session["cont"] = cont = cbSend.Checked ? cont + 1 : cont -1;

        // Prossiga com o que você quer fazer
}
```

Vale dizer no `Page_Load` inicialize o `Session["cont"] = 0` (se não for postback) para evitar que comportamento estranho ocorra durante navegação pelo site.

Comment: eu nao sei qual a solução, poste a solução como resposta pf.

Comment: Yes sir! Posted for you convenience.

Comment: dai como verifico se foi checado?

Comment: é so jogar o Session dentro do for? nao entendi

Comment: Fica mais fácil se você disser o que quer fazer, eu fiz um snipet baseado no seu exemplo.

Comment: quero mostrar o total selecionado

Comment: Então man, o valor deve estar dentro do cont, experimenta o código.

Comment: Ja mandei mostrar, ele so conta 1, ao selecionar outro item nao aumenta.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21612/discussion-between-war-lock-and-malkaviano).

Comment: entra no chat agora.